# Using crypto.randomInt() in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cryptography, create-react-app

I am trying to use `crypto.randomInt()` Nodejs API in a project bootstrapped with create-react-app that uses Webpack 5. I have tried multiple options like this so far:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify') },
  }
};
```

And then, `npm i crypto-browserify` as recommended by the error message.

```
// Returns Uncaught TypeError: randomInt is not a function
const { randomInt } = import('crypto');

console.log(randomInt(4));
```

From some threads, I tried:

```
// package.json
...
"browser": {
    "crypto": false
}
...
```

Still, no luck. I tried `import {randomInt} from 'crypto-browserify'`. This didn't work either.

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Prefer [`Crypto.getRandomValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) for web.

Comment: Yes, I looked into that as well. From MDN:  "getRandomValues() is the only member of the Crypto interface which can be used from an insecure context." Could you explain what "insecure context" means here?

Comment: Nevermind, found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts